# When I run my linkedin URL from my webpage it gives me an error

Tags: javascript, html, vs-web-site-project

What it's doing is trying to find the link on my website not going to the URL link.

Example: `bob.com/boblinkedin1234.com` when I need just `boblinkedin1234` to render

```
<li><a href="www.linkedin.com/in/shawn-mason-a03827ab"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the href with `https://`

i.e. the url should be `https://www.linkedin.com/` to tell the browser to not target the current website